# build ionc ios - Máquina virtual

Tags: ios, ionic

Alguém conhece algum serviço que disponibilize máquinas virtual com sistema operacional MAC ? Preciso somente para fazer o build de minha aplicação IONIC para poder gerar o aplicativo para IOS.

Comment: Conheço esse https://www.macincloud.com/ .

Comment: Legal, muito obrigado